# left border is detached/ broken layout with centered layout

Tags: css, sass

I want to center the pagination

However the left border is out of expectation

The [page link](http://great-compassion.com:1234/news/index)

How to fix it ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf0VC.png]

#### Stylesheet

```
.pagination a, .pagination span.current, .pagination span.gap {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pagination {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the left border to the block wrapper:

```css
.pagination {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Instead, you should add it to the first inner element:

```css
.pagination > span:first-child {
    border-left-width: 1px;
}
```